# Powershell to Remove an IP from a Windows Firewall rule scope

Tags: powershell, security, windows-server-2016, windows-firewall

I have a windows firewall Block rule where Ip's are getting added automatically by a PowerShell script triggered through a scheduled task based on an event.

I'm looking to create another PowerShell script which will query that firewall block rule gets the Remote addresses from there and remove the one which I pass through a variable.

```
   $Whitelist = 1.2.3.4
   #Get firewall object
   $fw = New-Object -ComObject hnetcfg.fwpolicy2
   #Get firewall rule named 'test' (must be created manually)
   $ar = $fw.rules | where {$_.name -eq 'test'}
   #Split the existing IPs into an array so we can search it for existing IPs
   $arRemote = $ar.RemoteAddresses -split(',')
   #Remove Ip from remote addresses
   $w = (Need Help Here)
   #Add the new IPs to firewall rule
   $w| %{
   if ($ar.RemoteAddresses -eq '*') {
   $ar.remoteaddresses = $_.Name
      }else{
        $ar.remoteaddresses += ',' + $_.Name
      }
    }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can simply use a `Where-Object` clause to filter out any IP that is in $WhiteList like this:

```
# set up the whitelist as array of strings
$Whitelist = '1.2.3.4', '10.10.2.1'
# filter all ips to block that are not found in the $Whitelist
$blockedIps = $ar.RemoteAddresses -split ',' | Where-Object { $whitelist -notcontains $_ }
# join the resulting ips with a comma and repopulate the RemoteAddresses property
$ar.RemoteAddresses = $blockedIps -join ','
```